# add an extra user to my simple php login script

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

This is my php login script. I found it on the web and it is working fine but...

Is there a solution to add one user?

```
<?

if ($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] != "user1" || $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"] != "pass1")
{

    header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Enter username and password to proceed\"");  
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");

    echo "<body>";
    echo "<div style='position:relative; margin:100px auto auto; width: 400px; height:auto; padding:20px; border:1px #ddd solid; color:#ff9900;'>Authentication failed.";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</body>";

    die();
}    
else
{
    echo "<div style='position:fixed; left:0px; top:90px; background-color:#000;    color:#ff9900; padding:4px; z-index: 999;'>Logged in.</div>";
}
?>
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(At the top:)

```
$users = array('User1' => 'Pass1', 'User2' => 'Pass2', );

if (!isset($users[$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]]) || $users[$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]] != $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"])
/* ... */
```

It saves the user data in an array and then checks if the data matches an entry.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to add the users to an array, to keep things tidy!

```
$users = array(
   'user1' => 'pass1',
   'user2' => 'pass2'
);
$user = $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"];
$pass = $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"];

if (array_key_exists($user, $users) && $users[$user] === $pass) {
    // Do your thang
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] == "user1" && $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"] == "pass1") ||      ($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] == "user2" && $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"] == "pass2"))
{
}
```

Comment: What if a third user needs to be added in future? This method will quickly turn into a mess

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$users = array('user1' => 'passw1',
               'user2' => 'passw2');

if (!array_key_exists($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"],$users) || $users[$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]] != $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"])
{

    header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Enter username and password to proceed\"");  
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");

    echo "<body>";
    echo "<div style='position:relative; margin:100px auto auto; width: 400px; height:auto; padding:20px; border:1px #ddd solid; color:#ff9900;'>Authentication failed.";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</body>";

    die();
}
```

Basically you store the users you want to have in an array; with the user names as the array keys and the user passwords as the array values.  Then you check to make sure that the user supplied is in the defined list and then you check to make sure the password is right.

That being said; this is not a very robust login solution so please be sure you're not using to protect anything sensitive.

Comment: Your version gave me an `unexpected T_IF` on line 8 when testing it. ;)

Comment: Oop thanks Fred; left out a semicolon after my array declaration